# How do i save multiple selected checkbox using jQuery , Ajax & MVC

Tags: javascript

**here is my HTML Code**

```
<table id="example" class="display select" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="1" id="example-select-all" /></th>
            <th>EmpID</th>
            <th>Employes Name</th>
            <th>Basic Salary</th>
 
            <th>Tax</th>
            <th>Total Allowance</th>
            <th>Total Deductions</th>
            <th>Gross Salary</th>
            <th>Taxable Income</th>
            <th>Net Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

```

```
**here is my script **



<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var table = $('#example').DataTable({
               
               'columnDefs': [{
                   'targets': 0,
                   'searchable': false,
                   'orderable': false,
                   'className': 'dt-body-center',
                   'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                       return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
                   }
               }],
               'order': [[1, 'asc']],
 
               "ajax":
                       {
                           "url": '/Payroll/GetEmplo',
                           "type": 'GET',
                           "datatype": 'JSON',
                           className: 'select-checkbox',
                           targets: 0,
                           orderable: false,
                       },
               "columns": [
 
                  { data: "" },
                 { data: "EmpID" },
                  { data: "EmpName" },
               { data: "BasicSalary" },
 
               { data: "Tax" },
               { data: "Total_Allowance" },
               { data: "Total_Deduction" },
               { data: "GrossSalary" },
               { data: "TaxableIncome" },
               { data: "NetSalary" },
 
               ],
           });
 
 
 
           // Handle click on "Select all" control
           $('#example-select-all').on('click', function () {
               // Get all rows with search applied
               var rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
               // Check/uncheck checkboxes for all rows in the table
               $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
           });
 
           // Handle click on checkbox to set state of "Select all" control
           $('#example tbody').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
               // If checkbox is not checked
               if (!this.checked) {
                   var el = $('#example-select-all').get(0);
                   // If "Select all" control is checked and has 'indeterminate' property
                   if (el && el.checked && ('indeterminate' in el)) {
                       // Set visual state of "Select all" control
                       // as 'indeterminate'
                       el.indeterminate = true;
                   }
               }
           });
           $('#SaveSalaryy').on('click', function () {
               var myCheckboxes = [];
               $('input:checkbox.example-select-all').each(function () {
                   if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                       myCheckboxes.push($(this).attr("value"));
                   }
               });
               var mySelectedValue = $('#example-select-all').find(":selected").text();
               var json = {
                   myCheckboxes: myCheckboxes,
                   mySelectedValue: mySelectedValue
               };
 
               var options = {};
               options.url = '/Payroll/SaveSalaryy';
               options.type = "POST";
               options.data = { "json": JSON.stringify(json) };
               options.dataType = "JSON";
               options.success = function (msg) {
                   alert(msg);
               };
               options.error = function () {
                   alert("Error while deleting the records!");
               };
               $.ajax(options);
           });
           
           // Handle form submission event
           $('#frm-example').on('submit', function (e) {
               var form = this;
 
               // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
               table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                   // If checkbox doesn't exist in DOM
                   if (!$.contains(document, this)) {
                       // If checkbox is checked
                       if (this.checked) {
                           // Create a hidden element
                           $(form).append(
                              $('<input>')
                                 .attr('type', 'hidden')
                                 .attr('name', this.name)
                                 .val(this.value)
                           );
                       }
                   }
               });
           });
 
       });
```

**here is my controller **

```
[HttpPost]
      public JsonResult SaveSalaryy(string json)
      {
          
          var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
          dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));
 
          //Get your variables here from AJAX call
          var checboxValues = jsondata["myCheckboxes"];
          var mySelectedValue = jsondata["mySelectedValue"];
          //Do your stuff
          // bool status = false;
          //var empd = DB.Calcs.FirstOrDefault();
          //if (empd != null)
          //{
              DB.Calcs.Add(mySelectedValue);
              DB.SaveChanges();
          //status = true;
          //}
          return mySelectedValue();
      }
```

but I received this error

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFLgK.png)

I just want to save selected checkbox into SQL database using jQuery, AJAX and asp.net MVC5 but I get the attached error below
so please guys can you help how to do it ?

am just new here so is there any one who can help me ?``

Comment: you want send checkbox value or whole tr data?

Comment: i just want to send checked checkbox value to sql database